# Why is my function proxy not being called in Node?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I was using proxy `get` method fine. Then I tried using it on a function and quickly realized I needed to use the `apply` method. This simple example is not working. It never enters apply.

Node looks to support apply https://node.green/#ES2015-built-ins-Proxy--apply--handler. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
var Foo = {
  runme: function() {
    return 1;
  }
};

var Magic = {
  Foo: Foo
};

Magic.Foo = new Proxy(Object.assign({}, Magic.Foo), {
  apply: function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
    // never gets in here
    console.log('Proxying function call');
    console.log(target);
    return 2;
  }
});

console.log(Foo.runme()); // outputs 1
console.log(Magic.Foo.runme()); // outputs 1
```

I tried both Proxy on `Magic.foo` directly and via the `Object.assign` to see if it needed to be its own object or not. Neither worked.

Comment: Yes, you should be using the `get` trap to capture `Magic.Foo.runme` accesses. Please show us your attempt and explain how it did not work.

Comment: http://2ality.com/2015/10/intercepting-method-calls.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume here that `apply` traps work like `get` traps -- i.e., for any property of the proxied object -- but they do not. The `apply` trap runs when the Proxy itself is called a function. Here, your proxy is `Magic.Foo`, but you never call `Magic.Foo()`. You only call `Magic.Foo.runme()`, which is not a proxied function.

You must wrap each function whose invocation you wish to intercept in its own individual `Proxy` wrapper.

Alternatively, you could use a `get` trap on `Magic.Foo` that returns a function with the appropriate behavior for each accessed property.

Answer (score 1):

The `apply` trap only applies to proxies over functions, which create callable objects (i.e. functions). A `new Proxy` created on a normal object (like your `{}`) creates a non-callable proxy object, which will never trigger `apply`.